# Is there an (official) API to get information from vCops?

Tags: vmware-vcenter

For a reporting tool I will need to grab the generated information from vCops (vmware vCenter Operations Manager). Therefore I am searching for an official, or at least well supported API.

For me it looks, like there is nothing official, right? 
The vCops adapter and REST API is just meant to grab information into vCops, but not to request those information from outside.

I took a look at the "REST" alike way, the vCops Webclient uses, but it uses Cookies, which is not REST compliant and I believe that its not such a good idea to use this, because it would require changes for a new vCops Version (which should be release soon).

There is an API for the [powershell API developed by vElemental](http://velemental.com/2014/03/15/unofficial-vcenter-operations-for-powercli-update/) , but I don't think, that this is a good way or?

So what else could I do, or what would you recommend me to get all those created information of vCops into an other tool?

Comment: What type of info do you need to pull?

Comment: I would like to get summarized information, for example the remaining capacity, which server has problems, how the vmware health-index, shown in vCops is, etc. It should be summarized with other informations, that couldn't be displayed by vCops.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can at least pull the VM health value from the vSphere API instead of vCops.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like VMware wants to make vCops your main monitoring solution. In other words, they make it easy to push data into vCops but hard to get data out of it because they don't want you to feed vCops data into another monitoring solution. At least that's how it feels like.

However, I've found a [this](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/393096) thread where someone says to have a look at `https://vcopsip/HttpPostAdapter/OpenAPIServlet`. I'm not sure if this helps you.

Comment: Well it looks, like its still an adapter meant to collect data, am I right? http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vcops-enterprise10-adapter-guide.pdf

Comment: Yes, it's there to POST data into vCops. But there are a few getter methods as well: http://twitpic.com/8dmlll

Answer (score 0):

In case you've updated to vRealize Operations in the meantime: There seems to be a new REST API that might help you.

```
https://your-vrops/suite-api
```

should give you the documentation. ([Tweet](https://twitter.com/lamw/status/542384443546025986))